# Fitting probabilities in scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-trees

This is a newbie questions, so please bear with me. Given this random forest model:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X = [ [2,1,1,1], [2,0,2,1], [3,1,1,1] ]
y = [ 0, 1, 2 ]

regr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, max_depth=5)
regr.fit(X, y)

X_test = [ [3, 1, 1, 1] ]    
y_result = regr.predict_proba(X_test)
print('y_result:' , y_result )
```

The result is:

```
y_result: [[0.26 0.05 0.69]]
```

I understand that these are the probabilities of the first, second and third value, or 0 = 26%, 1 = 5% and 2 = 69%.

Question: if the test set is `[3, 1, 1, 1]` and it fits to the value `2`, why do I get `69%` probability of `2` instead of `100%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on how this algorithm works, here is why :
You want to build `200 trees`, with a `max depth of 5 levels`. Each `tree` is a `decision tree`, train with a subset of your data. To answer your question, it doesn't fit to the value `2` because that's not how it works. What's happening is that `52` trees predicted the value `0`, 10 predicted the value `1`, and `138` predicted the value `2`. So most of the trees predicted the value `2` You asked for the probability (using `predict_proba(X_test)`). If you want only one value, don't use `predict_proba` but `predict(X_test)`. But it will only be the *reflect* of the probabilities you got.

Comment: thanks, it makes sense